# Add console log to each step in allure report?(Java, Selenium, TestNG, Cucumber)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, allure

I need to add the console log after each test step to the allure report. I use selenium, testng, cucumber, spring boot

I tried to get logs from driver with code:

```
Allure.addAttachment("Console log: ", String.valueOf(webDriverActions.getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).getAll()));
```

but it show empty mass []

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your code you will need to read the LogEntries

```
   LogEntries logEntries = webDriverActions.getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

    StringBuilder logs = new StringBuilder();


    for (org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry entry : logEntries) {
        logs.append(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " "
                + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
        logs.append(System.lineSeparator());

    }
    System.out.println(logs);
    Allure.addAttachment("Console log: ", logs);
```

Comment: Thanks, but Its returned empty string. Any ideas?, some library to connect with allure, or some Listeners?
Maybe you know how can I allow overview logs in step

Comment: If its returning empty string means there are no errors in the browser console.

Comment: But I need to add all console log to report at least. 
In best case it should be log after each step from start to end.

Comment: You can go for the WebDriverEventListener https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/ Or  In Allure https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/issues/747 @Step("{0}")
    public static void log(final String message){
        //intentionally empty
    }